# Remove everything before the first slash in a URL?

Tags: ruby, regex

Using regex, how could I remove everything before the first path `/` in a URL?

Example URL: `https://www.example.com/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org`

From that, I just want `/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org`

In the case that it's just the root domain (ie. `https://www.example.com/`), then I just want the `/` to be returned.

The domain may or may not have a subdomain and it may or may not have a secure protocol. Really ultimately just wanting to strip out *anything* before that first path slash.

In the event that it matters, I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: **Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.** You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

Don't use regex for this. Use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class. You can write:

```
require 'uri'

u = URI.parse('https://www.example.com/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org')
u.path #=> "/some/page"
u.query #=> "user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"

# All together - this will only return path if query is empty (no ?)
u.request_uri #=> "/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 require 'uri'

 uri = URI.parse("https://www.example.com/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org")

 > uri.path + '?' + uri.query
  => "/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"
```

As Gavin also mentioned, it's not a good idea to use RegExp for this, although it's tempting.
You could have URLs with special characters, even UniCode characters in them, which you did not expect when you wrote the RegExp. This can particularly happen in your query string.  Using the URI library is the safer approach.

Answer (score 0):

The same can be done using [`String#index`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#index-instance_method)

> index(substring[, offset])

```
str = "https://www.example.com/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"
offset = str.index("//") # => 6
str[str.index('/',offset + 2)..-1]
# => "/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* agree with the advice to use the URI module in this case, and I don't consider myself great with regular expressions.  Still, it seems worthwhile to demonstrate one possible way to do what you ask.

```
test_url1 = 'https://www.example.com/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org'
test_url2 = 'http://test.com/'
test_url3 = 'http://test.com'

regex = /^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(.*)/

regex.match(test_url1)[1]
# => "/some/page?user=1&email=joe@schmoe.org"

regex.match(test_url2)[1]
# => "/"

regex.match(test_url3)[1]
# => ""
```

Note that in the last case, the URL had no trailing `'/'` so the result is the empty string.

The regular expression (`/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(.*)/`) says the string starts with (`^`) `http` (`http`), optionally followed by `s` (`s?`), followed by `://` (`:\/\/`) followed by at least one non-slash character (`[^\/]+`), followed by zero or more characters, and we want to capture those characters (`(.*)`).

I hope that you find that example and explanation educational, and I again recommend against actually using a regular expression in this case.  The URI module is simpler to use and far more robust.